# undefined reference to function - why?

Tags: c, function

I'm very new at C language but I was learning how to implement function and I have the below error when I `gcc main.c`:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccr4DJ17.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `aireRectangle'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "air.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double resultat;
    resultat = aireRectangle(10.0, 20.0);
    printf("l'air du rectangle est %f\n", resultat);
    return 0;
}
```

Include the `air.h` function to be operational in my `main.c`,

To compile I used the command `gcc main.c`

**air.h**

```c
#ifndef air_h
#define air_h

#include <stdio.h>

double aireRectangle(double largeur, double hauteur);

#endif
```

Comment: Show the command you used to compile/link. It's incorrect. (And in the future, avoid putting leading line number on StackOverflow. It prevents us from, say, running it ourselves.)

Comment: Where is the `aireRectangle` function defined? In another c file that you didn't compile and link with the main c file?

Comment: You're likely missing a `-l` option to tell the linker which library to link. Whereever you got `air.h` from should tell you what the specific option is.

Comment: Now might be a good time to learn about the concepts of [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). A translation unit is, in essence, a *single source file with all included header files. If you have multiple source files, you need to build with them all, to get all translation units into the finished executable program.

Comment: Thank i'll study that

Comment: OT: you shouldn't have `#include <stdio.h>` in air.h. Only include what you actually need in air.h (IOW nothing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not linking in the object that contains `aireRectangle`.

Assuming it's provided by accompanying `air.c`, you can use

```bash
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o myprog main.c air.c
```

which is basically short for

```bash
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.c -c               # Compile main.c.
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic air.c -c                # Compile air.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o myprog main.o air.o  # Link them.
```

Note that you should always enable your compiler's warnings. I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, which I've included above.

Comment: @Eyzou don't write "thank you comments" but upvote/accept the answer.